# Issue with line chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tableau-desktop

I am very new to MS Power BI and I am trying to create a line chart that tracks progress over time.  I am replicating something I built in Tableau with the same data set - but MS Power BI doesn't seem to recognize it is a progression over time as easily.  I think the question may be a bit simple but since I am new to this software, reaching out to see if anyone can spot the issue.  All of the data points congregate on one date - when I would expect them to display a line of progress over time.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Sum Aggregations in Y axis for values. Use 'Don't Summarize' for Y values.